# How to understand `yield from` in python coroutine?

Tags: python, coroutine, yield-from

The code come form [Fluent Python 1st edtion](https://github.com/fluentpython/example-code/blob/master/16-coroutine/coroaverager3.py),

I cannot understand the line `while True:` in `grouper`, delete that line raise a `StopIteration` error.

But I find a new version of `grouper` without `while True:` that works. Why `group.send(None)` need another loop in `while True:` (or another `results[key] = yield from averager()`)?

My understanding is `group.send(None)` will stop `yield from averager()` and assign `results[key]` a value(`Result(count, average)`). That's all.

```py
from collections import namedtuple

Result = namedtuple('Result', 'count average')


# the subgenerator
def averager():  # <1>
    total = 0.0
    count = 0
    average = None
    while True:
        term = yield  # <2>
        if term is None:  # <3>
            break
        total += term
        count += 1
        average = total/count
    return Result(count, average)  # <4>


# the delegating generator
def grouper(results, key):  # <5>
    while True:  # <6>
        results[key] = yield from averager()  # <7>

# Another version works
#def grouper(results, key):
#    results[key] = yield from averager()
#    results[key] = yield from averager()

# the client code, a.k.a. the caller
def main(data):  # <8>
    results = {}
    for key, values in data.items():
        group = grouper(results, key)  # <9>
        next(group)  # <10>
        for value in values:
            group.send(value)  # <11>
        group.send(None)  # important! <12>

    # print(results)  # uncomment to debug
    report(results)


# output report
def report(results):
    for key, result in sorted(results.items()):
        group, unit = key.split(';')
        print('{:2} {:5} averaging {:.2f}{}'.format(
              result.count, group, result.average, unit))


data = {
    'girls;kg':
        [40.9, 38.5, 44.3, 42.2, 45.2, 41.7, 44.5, 38.0, 40.6, 44.5],
    'girls;m':
        [1.6, 1.51, 1.4, 1.3, 1.41, 1.39, 1.33, 1.46, 1.45, 1.43],
    'boys;kg':
        [39.0, 40.8, 43.2, 40.8, 43.1, 38.6, 41.4, 40.6, 36.3],
    'boys;m':
        [1.38, 1.5, 1.32, 1.25, 1.37, 1.48, 1.25, 1.49, 1.46],
}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makes me remember how *nice* ascynio is, and why everybody should use it...

What is happening is best explained by walking through the operation of the iterators.  This is the inner generator, simplified:

```py
def averager():
    local_var
    while True:
        term = yield
        if term is None:
            break
        local_var = do_stuff(term)
    return local_var
```

This does *two* things.  Firstly, it gets some data with `yield` (ugh, explaining *that* choice of words is just confusing) so long as that data isn't `None`.  Then when it *is* `None`, it raises a `StopIterationException` with the value of `local_var`.  (This is what returning from a generator does).

Here is the outer generator:

```py
def grouper(results, key):
    while True:
        results[key] = yield from averager()
```

What *this* does is *to expose the inner generator's yield* up to the calling code, *until* the inner generator raises `StopIterationException`, which is silently captured (by the `yield from` statement) and assigned.  Then it gets ready to do the same thing again.

Then we have the calling code:

```py
def main(data):
    results = {}
    for key, values in data.items():
        group = grouper(results, key)
        next(group)
        for value in values:
            group.send(value)
        group.send(None)
```

What *this* does is:

- it iterates the outer generator exactly once
- this exposes the inner generator's yield, and it uses that (`.send`) to communicate with the inner generator.
- it 'ends' the inner generator by sending `None`, at which point the first `yield from` statement ends, and assigns the value passed up.
- **at this point, the outer generator gets ready to send another value**
- the loop moves on, and the generator is deleted by garbage collection.

> what's with the `while True:` loop?

Consider this code, which also works for the outer generator:

```py
def grouper(result, key):
    result[key] = yield from averager
    yield 7
```

The only important thing is that the generator should not be exhausted, so it doesn't pass an exception up the chain saying 'I have nothing left to iterate'.

P.S. confused?  I was.  I had to check this out, it's a while since I've tried to use generator based coros.  They're scheduled for deletion---use asyncio, it's *much* nicer.

Comment: Thank you for detail explanation, I finally got that `StopIteration` without `while True:` comes from the exhausted outer generator, so another `yield` is used to supress it.